# How to call Java object from CDI bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, cdi

I have a CDI bean with Java object which I use to display profile data from Database:

***Parent Bean***

```
@Named("DCProfileTabGeneralController")
@ViewScoped
public class DCProfileTabGeneral implements Serializable
{

    public DCObj dc;

    public class DCObj
    {

        private int componentStatsId;                 // COMPONENTSTATSID   NUMBER(38,0)
        ........
        // Default Constructor
        public DCObj(){};

        public DCObj(int componentStatsId....)
        {

            this.componentStatsId = componentStatsId;
            .......

        }

        public int getComponentStatsId()
        {
            return componentStatsId;
        }

        public void setComponentStatsId(int componentStatsId)
        {
            this.componentStatsId = componentStatsId;
        }
        ....
    }

    // Getters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public DCObj getdcData()
    {
        return dc;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initData() throws SQLException
    {
        initDBData();
    }

    // Generate data Object from Oracle
    public void initDBData() throws SQLException
    {
                dc = new DCObj(result.getInt("COMPONENTSTATSID"),
                .........
    }
}
```

***Validator***

```
@Named("ValidatorDatacenterController")
@ViewScoped
public class ValidatorDatacenter implements Validator, Serializable
{

    public ValidatorDatacenter()
    {
    }

    @Inject
    private DCProfileTabGeneral profileTabGeneral;


    // Validate Datacenter Name
    public void validateDatacenterName(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException, SQLException
    {
        int componentStatsId = -1;

        if (profileTabGeneral != null)
        {
            DCObj dcData = profileTabGeneral.dc;
            if (dcData != null)
            {
                componentStatsId = dcData.getComponentStatsId();
            }
        }

        if (componentStatsId == -1)
        {
            return;
        }

        String l;
        String s;

        if (value != null && !(s = value.toString().trim()).isEmpty())
        {

            if (s.length() > 18)
            {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  Value is too long! (18 digits max)", null));
            }

            if (ds == null)
            {
                throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
            }

            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs;
            int resComponentStatsId = -1;
            try
            {
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                // if componentsstatsid <> edited componentstatsid in jsf -> throw validator exception
                ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT componentstatsid from COMPONENTSTATS where NAME = ?");
                ps.setString(1, s);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next())
                {
                    resComponentStatsId = rs.getInt(1);
                }

                if (resComponentStatsId != -1 && resComponentStatsId != componentStatsId)
                {
                    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                            "  '" + s + "' is already in use!", null));
                }

            }
            catch (SQLException x)
            {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  SQL error!", null));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ps != null)
                {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                  "  This field cannot be empty!", null));
        }

    }
```

}

I have a custom validator which checks the input values from the profile page into the Database. I tested to get the Java object from the parent page using @Inject and to pass the Ojject to the validator. It turns out that I get empty Java object every time when I use @Inject.

I also tested to get Int using CDI. It works but when I again tested to get the Java Object again I get empty Object.

Can you tell me what is the proper way to call a Java Object from CDI bean? Why I cannot get Java object from CDI bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly CDI injection will not work with a validator. Use advanced from Myfaces CODI as the JSF-module from deltaspike is not ready yet. https://cwiki.apache.org/EXTCDI/jsf-usage.html

Or go for deltaspike and use the BeanProvider to get your instance.

```
BeanProvider.getContextualReference(DCProfileTabGeneral .class, false);
```

Comment: I tested to insert manually data into the Java Object: `private int componentStatsId = 100` and it work, the value is passed using CDI. I don't understand why I cannot populate the Java object with data from the DB. I always get empty object. And in my case I don't have a standard JSF validator. I have a CDI bean for validator.

Comment: Just idea why the data is always null: Both CDI beans have ViewScope. But when I hard code the object with value I get proper data. It turns out that I get one instance displayed from the JSF page and one instance loaded from the validator. The same code is loaded twice I suppose but the data is isolated. Is there a way to share the object into one user session?

Comment: @Peter Penzov Calling validateDatacenterName from a facelet won't work even if your bean is Named as I explained in my post.

JSF 2 finished early in Java EE 6 and CDI late, integration is not perfect.

Another note, Try using SessionScoped because ViewScoped is JSF scope (unless you use myfaces CODI).

If sessionScoped works for you replace it with ConversationScoped if you want or one of several scopes available from CODI.

Comment: @PeterPenzov You are welcome. I must recommend you to the deltaspike solution because any CDI project of size will benefit from it.